# Get canvas circle current radius set with arc()

Tags: javascript, canvas

i have set circle on canvas like this:

```
    var ctx = $element.getContext("2d");
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(100, 100, 50, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
```

Questions is how can I retrieve arc values later, as I am interested to see radius value of the circle?

```
console.log( ctx.arc() ) // this does not work
```

Comment: store it in a variable.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the 2D context API's functions are just render functions. They render content to the canvas and for the most part forget what and where.

If you wish to keep track of what you draw you will have to build a reference list / array of some type.

eg

```
 const arcs = [];
 ctx.arc(x,y,r,0,Math.PI*2);
 arcs.push({x,y,r});
```

You can then access it via the array.

```
 console.log(arcs[0].r);
```

Though the common practice is to define an object that is an arc and store them in an array. The arc has a draw function that renders to the canvas.

```
 const arc = {
     x : 0,  // defaults
     y : 0,
     r : 0,
     draw() {
         ctx.arc(this.x,this.y,this.r,0,Math.PI * 2);
     }
 }

 function createArc(x,y,r){
      return Object.assign({},arc,{x,y,r});
 }
 const arcs = [];
 arcs.push(createArc(100,100,50));
 arcs[0].draw();
 console.log(arcs[0].r);
```